# change origine barplot R ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to let a space at the origin of my graph (remove left corner (350000,17) coordinate).

my dataset (dat):

```
group  x       y
Sens 17    4059
Sens 18    3289
Sens 19    3785
Sens 20    5241
Sens 21   17179
Sens 22   11004
Sens 23   23624
Sens 24   61544
Sens 25   87324
Sens 26   85610
Sens 27   53652
Sens 28   26243
Sens 29   10840
Sens 30    3277
Antisens 17   -7145
Antisens 18   -8334
Antisens 19  -10020
Antisens 20  -14247
Antisens 21  -33285
Antisens 22  -32575
Antisens 23  -79349
Antisens 24 -217690
Antisens 25 -338036
Antisens 26 -291708
Antisens 27 -172231
Antisens 28  -86063
Antisens 29  -29685
Antisens 30   -7914
```

How can I do that ?[image]

I would like to obtain something like this :
[image]

command line used :

```
d <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=group)) + 
       geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity") + 
       scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-350000, 90000),breaks=c(90000,0,-90000,-180000,-270000,-350000),labels=abs(c(90000,0,-90000,-180000,-270000,-350000))) + 
       scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(17,30,by=1), labels=c(17,"",19,"",21,"",23,"",25,"",27,"",29,"")) + 
       xlab("small RNA length [nt]") + ylab("normalized small RNA counts") + 
       scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
d <- d + theme_bw() + 
           theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + 
           theme(panel.border=element_blank())
d
```

Comment: What does 'dat' look like? We can't run your code without it. Please try to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Why not simply remove that datapoint from the dataset that you're plotting?

Comment: @sebastian-c I think its not to do with the datapoint, its todo with the axis lines meeting at the origin. Subtle.

Comment: Yes i would like that the left corner don't touch (as for the second images), i want a space not corner

Comment: Make your own graphics device.

Comment: A way to do this is remove the axis from your plot and then specify two segments with your desired range.

Comment: I try with d <- d + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(17,30),ylim=c(-350000, 90000)) but it's not what y want, any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment, `geom_segment` can be used to recreate the axis. I have tweaked the limits of your axis to allow for the extra space. I am not aware of another way to proceed, although i'm sure there will be. I have tried to comment the additions made to your code.

```
# Your data [you can use dput(dat) to get structure below]

dat <- structure(list(group = c("Sens", "Sens", "Sens", "Sens", "Sens", 
      "Sens", "Sens", "Sens", "Sens", "Sens", "Sens", "Sens", "Sens", 
      "Sens", "Antisens", "Antisens", "Antisens", "Antisens", "Antisens", 
      "Antisens", "Antisens", "Antisens", "Antisens", "Antisens", "Antisens", 
      "Antisens", "Antisens", "Antisens"), x = c(17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
      21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
      20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L), y = c(4059L, 
      3289L, 3785L, 5241L, 17179L, 11004L, 23624L, 61544L, 87324L, 
      85610L, 53652L, 26243L, 10840L, 3277L, -7145L, -8334L, -10020L, 
     -14247L, -33285L, -32575L, -79349L, -217690L, -338036L, -291708L, 
     -172231L, -86063L, -29685L, -7914L)), .Names = c("group", "x", 
     "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -28L))


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
library(ggplot2)

# Initial plot
d <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=group)) + 
         geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity") + 
         scale_y_continuous(
                 limits=c(-380000, 90000), # lowered the min limit slightly
                 breaks=c(90000,0,-90000,-180000,-270000,-350000),
                 labels=abs ,  # note the use of abs
                 expand=c(0,0)) + # use expand so axis start exactly at limits
         scale_x_continuous(
                 limits=c(16,30),  # added x-axis limits (min is < your min break)
                 breaks=seq(18,30,by=2), 
                 labels=seq(18,30,by=2) , 
                 expand=c(0,0)) + 
         xlab("small RNA length [nt]") + 
         ylab("normalized small RNA counts") + 
         scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))

d <- d + theme_bw() + 
         theme(axis.line = element_blank(), # remove both axis lines
               panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
               panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
               panel.border=element_blank())

# Add in segments for the axis - allow a gap at the corner
d + 
geom_segment(x=17,xend=30,y=-380000,yend=-380000) + # x-axis
geom_segment(x=16,xend=16,y=-350000,yend=90000) # y-axis
```

[image]